# API-Centric app in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, api, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.3

I want to make API (Laravel) and SPA (Vue.js) that uses this API. But I am not sure how to accomplish that.

2 separate projects (1 Laravel project for API and 1 Vue.js project for SPA)
or
1 Laravel project for both API (routes/api.php) and SPA (routes/web.php)

Which one to choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separated projects are more clean and organized while all in one project is more practical.
What I do is create two different repositories ((project-api or project-server or project-backend) and (project-client or project-frontend)) if is a medium-large project and work on them completely separated. Both projects don't know nothing about each other.

Obs: The routing system on frontend is not managed by Laravel as appeared in what you wrote here `and SPA (routes/web.php)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use separate projects, I suggest you use [Vue-CLI](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) for scaffolding Vue.js projects and [Vue-Resource](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource) for web requests (XmlHttpRequest or JSONP)

Laravel also provides [Laravel Elixir](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir) that support CSS and Javascript using [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com) and [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/).

First, You must install `node.js` and `npm`, from there on I would suggest that you read the documentation to get you going further.